# Export without Render function in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

In my React Native application, i am trying to add a component where i'll perform some config tasks but that component won't render anything. I have made the component already but when i import that on `App.tsx` the fucntion doesn't get called. How to import this following component properly to `App.tsx`. The component is given below:

```js
var androidVersion = VersionInfo.appVersion;
var iosVersion = VersionInfo.buildVersion;

function usePrevious(value) {
    const ref = useRef();
    useEffect(() => {
      ref.current = value;
    });
    return ref.current;
}

const Config = () => {
    console.log('check if get called >>',showVersionCodeStatus);
    const prevAmount = usePrevious(iosVersion);
    useEffect(() => {
        if(prevAmount.iosVersion !== iosVersion) {
         // process here
        }
        if(prevAmount.androidVersion !== androidVersion) {

            // process here
        }
    }, [iosVersion,androidVersion])
    // return {showVersionCodeStatus};
    
}

export default Config;
```

i'm importing the component in my `App.tsx` like the following:

```
import './config';
```

But it doesn't call the Config function. I have tried the following too:

```
import Config from './config';
```

That doesn't seem to work too. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Since `Config` does not render anything, you should export it as a custom hook with a name such as `useConfig`. Subsequently you can import and use your custom hook in `App.tsx`, which will then run the config tasks specified in your `useConfig` custom hook.

**useConfig.ts**

```
var androidVersion = VersionInfo.appVersion;
var iosVersion = VersionInfo.buildVersion;

function usePrevious(value) {
   const ref = useRef();
   useEffect(() => {
     ref.current = value;
   });
   return ref.current;
}

const useConfig = () => {
   console.log('check if get called >>',showVersionCodeStatus);
   const prevAmount = usePrevious(iosVersion);
   useEffect(() => {
       if(prevAmount.iosVersion !== iosVersion) {
        // process here
       }
       if(prevAmount.androidVersion !== androidVersion) {

           // process here
       }
   }, [iosVersion,androidVersion])
   // return {showVersionCodeStatus};
   
}

export default useConfig;
```

**App.tsx**

```
import useConfig from "./useConfig";

export default function App() {
  const config = useConfig();
  return (
      ...
  );
}
```